# Why aren't digital signatures the standard way to authenticate web clients?

Tags: authentication, cryptography

The web is a mess of incompatible cookie schemes, asinine requirements ("your password must contain letters, numbers, and at least one symbol from !()-_., and must begin with a letter, and once you change it you can't reuse it"), and unreliable (not to mention centralized) third-party authentication protocols.

It seems to me that the web would be more secure and standardized if public keys were universally treated as online identities the way email addresses currently are. Authenticating a piece of information would be as simple as signing it cryptographically. It could even happen on the application layer, e.g. with an HTTP header `Signature: algorithm=sha256;encoding=base64;signed-digest=...;public-key=...`

Is public key cryptography truly unfit to serve universal identification and authentication on all internet layers? Or is non-cryptographic authentication a market failure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are quick to point out the defects of passwords — and you're right. But no other method has all the advantages of passwords, so any replacement method comes with benefits and costs.

On this topic, I recommend the work by the [security group at Cambridge](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/projects/). You may be interested in the [authentication tag on their blog](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/category/authentication/). A recent paper on the topic is [The quest to replace passwords: a framework for comparative evaluation of Web authentication schemes](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-817.html)) summarized in [this blog post](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2012/05/22/the-quest-to-replace-passwords/).

Unfortunately, the paper does not analyze the scheme you propose, with private keys stored on the user's PC and public keys provided by the user at enrollment time as part of their identity. But we can look at the criteria used in the paper and see which ones fail.

[image: Comparative evaluation of various authentication schemes]

- *Scalable-for-Users*: that depends whether you expect users to have a single identity or one per service.
- *Nothing-to-Carry*: as long as you accept that the private keys will be stored in a mobile phone, your scheme has the *Quasi-Nothing-to-Carry* property.
- *Easy-Recovery-from-Loss*: ok as long as the private key is used for authentication exclusively — changing the private key is as easy as a password reset. (The authors do not consider password resets within the scope of their study.)
- *Server-Compatible*: no, like just about any other alternative to passwords, servers must be modified. This is admittedly more of a marketing than a technical issue.
- *Browser-Compatible*: this would depend on how the private key is used on the client (this has implications on security).
- *Resilient-to-Theft*: passwords are not very resilient, but memorized passwords are resilient to theft, unlike a key stored on a device.

The two major hurdles I see are the risk of device theft and management of multiple identities. Device theft can be countered to some extent by protecting the private key with a password, but the key file is subject to unlimited high-speed brute force search by the attacker, unlike passwords used for online authentication which can be throttled.

Management of multiple identities is a bigger problem: it means the user must decide whether to use the same identity on multiple sites or not. Reusing the same key is convenient but trivially discoverable so it is a major privacy concern. While it is a bad idea for security, users can (and do) reuse passwords with no privacy implication. Using different identities on different sites requires cumbersome management of multiple keys, which is more burden than typical users want. A better scheme would combine the private keys with some repository of secrets, which shares all the difficulties with password managers.

Comment: You can fix the theft problem by creating copies of your identity across devices you own...   or a "threshold of trustees" which can use your identity (wife + lawyer == me when i die).   This kind of management can be done with simple apps, in a distributed manner using QR for secure device-to-device communication when needed.   Making this a standard would end the "password problem", and allow people to register their identity instead of a password.   People can have more secure (M of 2 required) and less secure (M of 1 is OK) identities as well...

Answer (score 9):

The simplest answer is that key/certificate distribution is a difficult and expensive problem.

For certificates to work securely, you generally need some trusted authorities (typically CAs) to sign the certificates. Who would do this? You can't expect some trusted entity to go around and approve every internet user's certificate. You could use a web of trust, but this has it's own [complications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust#Web_of_trust_problems) (Which signatures do we trust? Will casual internet users care about endorsing other people's certificates? Is it even secure to let them do so?). What about certificate revocation? How could you handle that nicely with millions of clients?

Comment: According to the first sentence of the question, I'd say that self-signed certificates would be the equivalent. But it has other problems, e.g., you can hardly expect to have it with you when being out of office/home.

Comment: For what the OP is suggesting, no CA is needed at all.

Comment: "_For certificates to work securely_" as an alternative for email + password; you just need a key pair, stored on your PC and directly used by your browser. You do not need CA, web of trust, etc. You might want these, but even without, it is still better than just identification with an email address.

Answer (score 3):

[Federated Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity) is the name of the problem you describe.

> A federated identity in information technology is the means of linking a person's electronic identity and attributes, stored across multiple distinct identity management systems.

The reason it hasn't happened on the web is that the web wasn't designed for it from the ground up, and it's a really hard problem to solve.  The path of least resistance for most web-sites has been to manage their own password DB.

To understand the problems, consider that

1. Users want to be able to move from one device to another, but there aren't easy hardware solutions for moving key-stores securely from one device to another.
2. A single identity isn't obviously more robust against malware -- it may just become a single point of failure.  If malware gets onto one machine, and steals a single private key for the whole web (or a large portion thereof), then you're in trouble.  Malware can steal passwords by key-logging, but only for those sites you visit while it persists.

Comment: Most of the problems with multiple devices is because the hardware to identify and authenticate a person is not standard.  Half the devices can identify you from your Face, the other half want your fingerprint, another quater wants a security passphrase or pin, the last quater can do all of the above.  Until we as customers do all of the above, a standard authentication system can't be deloyed, or at least not at the levels where they are used by even the smallest players.

Comment: @Ramhound, The OP asked why there is not a standard concept of identity based on asymmetric key pairs.  If the authentication is just used to decide which secret to use to sign a network message, then the mode of authentication is irrelevant.  I happen to think that authentication needs to be distinguished from authorization, and that we should focus on authority stores, not stores of identity.

Comment: @Ramhound "_Half the devices can identify you from your Face, the other half want your fingerprint_" these face or fingerprint technologies should only be used where **no security at all** is needed, or expected.

Comment: @curiousguy, Yeah.  If I can get photos that someone is tagged in via the Facebook API, then I can systematically attack face recognition.  Any idea how many bits of entropy there are in fingerprints?  ["The Myth of “The Myth of Fingerprints”"](http://ericmalm.net/ac/research/mcm04/umap-215-230.pdf) puts the number at 10^-9 which would imply 30b but partials would probably have to be accepted reducing that.

Comment: @MikeSamuel The reliability of comparisons of fingerprints scanned by specialists is one thing, the reliability of a cheap electronic fingerprint reader is another.

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to economics.

Password security isn't perfect. But it is good enough for most problems in the online world. It also happens to be simple enough for most people to grasp -- even if they oftentimes forget the password itself. Password security also happens to be implementable on just about any platform and user interface you can think of. Oftentimes it is so commonplace as to be baked into your toolkit already.

Certificate style security is nightmarishly expensive to stand up, as [Oleksi points out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/159083/3762). And you would also have challenges with getting people to be able to use it. Especially in a multi-device world like today. Imagine the fun of helping your mother install her certificate on her smart car.

Comment: You do not need a smart card to beat the security of the usual email address + password; you just need a key pair, stored on your PC and directly used by your browser. You do not _need_ CA, web of trust, secure hardware, crypto processor, smart-card, anything like that. You might also want all this stuff, but that's another story.

Comment: Ask 10 people on the street what a keypair is. Let me know how that goes. Also, how would you login from a computer where you didn't have your keypair installed?

Comment: Ask 10 people on the street what OFDM is. Let me know how that goes. Yet many of them probably use DSL, DOCSIS, or at least DVB every day. People do not need to understand the mathematical principles of asymmetric crypto, only that: **1) possession of the certificate is their proof of online identity, and 2) the certificate fingerprint is their online identity**. If it was well integrated in websites, people would use it. 20 years ago, these 10 people perhaps did not knew about "email" either, but they learnt fast, and they now have many different online identities.

Comment: The difficult problem is not user understanding, it is certificate mobility. Users need a simple way to use their private key on many different computers that is universal, simple to use, cheap and moderately safe.

Comment: If you think my OFDM example is silly, these 10 people certainly use at least one of HTTP/TLS, POP/TLS or IMAP/TLS, so they already use certificates. If they download any programs on Windows Vista, the UAC interface shows them the identity of signer of the downloaded program. They are already exposed to the concept of digital signature.

Comment: @curiousguy -- yup, many people are regularly using PKI. But most folks only understand "don't trust your credit card to a site without the little gold lock icon". Furthermore, in my experience, people are really uncomfortable with the idea that some bit of digital gibberish is their identity.